# How to regenerate razor web.config in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have accidentally deleted the razor web.config file in my Asp.Net MVC 5 project. Is it possible to regenerate it?

Comment: Well, when you mention `razor web.config` I assume you mean the web.config in your view folder by default. Either way, you can simply create a new MVC project and copy/paste the web.config you need.

Comment: Assuming you can't recover it from anywhere (source control, Recycle Bin, etc.) then tweray's suggestion is a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure that there's no other way to accomplish that.